# Looping into gridview using javascript: only the last one is displayed correctly

Tags: javascript, asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview:

```
# | Status   | ReturnCode
1 | Imported | 
2 | Imported | 
3 | Imported |
```

...which should be updated row by row. So I have a button that when clicked, will turn the gridview into this, while each row is waiting for the update (which is done by web service / pagemethods call):

```
# | Status   | ReturnCode
1 | Pending  | 
2 | Pending  |  
3 | Pending  |
```

Based from the return value from the update, it should show one-by-one update like this:

```
# | Status      | ReturnCode
1 | Successful  | 1.0.0
2 | Pending     | //updating.... 
3 | Pending     |
```

..so after all the updates, it should show like:

```
# | Status      | ReturnCode
1 | Successful  | 1.0.0
2 | Successful  | 1.0.0 
3 | Successful  | 1.0.0
```

..but the problem is it shows like this:

```
# | Status      | ReturnCode
1 | Pending     | 
2 | Pending     |  
3 | Successful  | 1.0.0
```

How can I fix this?

For your reference, here are my scripts:
(called by Update button)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function updateGrid() {
        var grid = document.getElementById("<%=gv.ClientID%>");

        for (var i = 0; i < grid.rows.length - 1; i++) {
            var statusLabel = grid.rows[i + 1].cells[4].childNodes[1];
            statusLabel.innerText = "Pending";
        }

        updateEachRow(grid);
    }
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function updateEachRow(grid) {
       for (var j = 0; j < grid.rows.length - 1; j++) {
            var index = j + 1;
            var acctno = grid.rows[index].cells[1].childNodes[1];
            var mobile = grid.rows[index].cells[2].childNodes[1];
            var operation = grid.rows[index].cells[3].childNodes[1];
            var statusLabel = grid.rows[index].cells[4].childNodes[1];
            var statCodeLabel = grid.rows[index].cells[5].childNodes[1];

            PageMethods.UpdateRow(acctno.innerText, mobile.innerText, operation.innerText, OnResult);

            function OnResult(result) {
                statusLabel.innerText = (result == "1.0.0" ? "Successful" : "Failed");
                statCodeLabel.innerText = result;
            }
        }
    }    
</script>
```

I hope I had explained my problem clearly enough.
Thanks for all the help. :)

Comment: are you binding your grid on page load?

Comment: no, another button binds the grid.

Comment: I tried a code similar to your code,what i found was before the last iteration in your loop,page load is called and due to which all the values which you are assigning in your loop gets lost and only last value remains.

Comment: try `return false` after executing your javascript code and prevent page load after button click. I hope you got my point